Why are drawings on top of PDFPageOverlay not saved in the PDF?
I am trying to write a SwiftUI app that allows a user to use an Apple Pencil to annotate a PDF leveraging the code here : https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10089/ and a Swift version I found here: https://github.com/GuillaumeRossit/MyPencilKitOverPDFApp/blob/main/MyPencilKitOverPDFApp/MyOverlayCoordinator.swift
The view responsible for opening and displaying the PDF is an UI view ("ViewerView") that utilizes PDFViewer, a UIViewRepresentable and PDFKit to display the PDF:
struct ViewerView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var documentStore: DocumentStore
var documentIndex: Int
@State private var showingBookmarks = false
@State private var selectedPageIndex: Int? = nil

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        PDFViewer(documentIndex: documentIndex, goToPageAtIndex: $selectedPageIndex)
        .environmentObject(documentStore)
        .onChange(of: documentStore.documents[documentIndex].bookmarks) { _ in
            documentStore.saveDocumentPaths()// Assuming this function handles saving
        }
        .onAppear() {
            documentStore.documents[documentIndex].myPDFDocument?.open { success in
                if !success {
                    print("Failed to open document")
                } else {
                    print("PDFDocument memory address when opening: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(documentStore.documents[documentIndex].myPDFDocument!.pdfDocument!).toOpaque())")
                    }
                }
        }
        
        Button("Save") {
           
            documentStore.documents[documentIndex].saveDocument()
            
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Bookmarks") {
                    showingBookmarks = true
                }
            }
        }
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingBookmarks) {
            // Create a binding to the specific DocumentModel's bookmarks
            let bookmarksBinding = $documentStore.documents[documentIndex].bookmarks
                    
            BookmarkListView(bookmarks: bookmarksBinding, onSelect: { pageIndex in
                selectedPageIndex = pageIndex
            }, isPresented: $showingBookmarks)
        }

    }
}

}
The PDFViewer code is below:
struct PDFViewer: UIViewRepresentable {
@EnvironmentObject var documentStore: DocumentStore
var documentIndex: Int

let overlayProvider = OverlayCoordinator()
//@Binding var bookmarks: Set<Int>
@Binding var goToPageAtIndex: Int?

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    
    
    pdfView.pageOverlayViewProvider = overlayProvider
    let documentModel = documentStore.documents[documentIndex]
          
    pdfView.document = documentModel.myPDFDocument?.pdfDocument
    
    print("PDFDocument memory address in PDFViewer: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(documentModel.myPDFDocument!.pdfDocument!).toOpaque())")
    pdfView.autoScales = true
    context.coordinator.pdfView = pdfView
    
    // for debugging whether I am using the right pdfpage class
    
    print("PDF document has \(documentModel.myPDFDocument!.pdfDocument!.pageCount) pages.")
    for i in 0...documentModel.myPDFDocument!.pdfDocument!.pageCount-1 {
        
        if let page = documentModel.myPDFDocument!.pdfDocument!.page(at: i) {
            print("Page type was \(type(of: page))")
        }
    }

    pdfView.isInMarkupMode = true
    
    let doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleDoubleTap(_:)))
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    pdfView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
    
    
    return pdfView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) {
    let documentModel = documentStore.documents[documentIndex]
    uiView.document = documentModel.myPDFDocument?.pdfDocument

    if let pageIndex = goToPageAtIndex, let page = documentModel.myPDFDocument?.pdfDocument!.page(at: pageIndex) {
            uiView.go(to: page)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Reset the index to prevent repetitive navigation
                self.goToPageAtIndex = nil
            }
        }
    }

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

}
The OverlayCoordinator (which implements PDFPageOverlayProvider) is below:
class OverlayCoordinator: NSObject, PDFPageOverlayViewProvider {
var pageToViewMapping = [PDFPage: PKCanvasView]()
 
  func pdfView(_ view: PDFView, overlayViewFor page: PDFPage) -> UIView? {
      var resultView: PKCanvasView? = nil
      
      if let overlayView = pageToViewMapping[page] {
          resultView = overlayView
      } else {
          let canvasView = PKCanvasView(frame: .zero)
          canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
          canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .systemYellow, width: 20)
          canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
          pageToViewMapping[page] = canvasView
          resultView = canvasView
      }
      
      // If we have stored a drawing on the page, set it on the canvas
      let page = page as! MyPDFPage
      print("In overlayview page type was \(type(of: page))")
      if let drawing = page.drawing {
          resultView?.drawing = drawing;
      }
      return resultView
  }

  func pdfView(_ pdfView: PDFView, willEndDisplayingOverlayView
      overlayView: UIView, for page: PDFPage) {
      let overlayView = overlayView as! PKCanvasView
      let page = page as! MyPDFPage
      page.drawing = overlayView.drawing
      pageToViewMapping.removeValue(forKey: page)
  }

}
I can draw just fine on the overlay. However, when saving using the following the console tells me it never finds any drawings on the MyPDFPage:
   override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {
    
    if let pdfDocument = pdfDocument {
        
        // Go through all pages in the document
        for i in 0...pdfDocument.pageCount-1 {
            
            if let page = pdfDocument.page(at: i) {
                
                if let page = (page as? MyPDFPage) {
                    print("Page type was \(type(of: page)) - proceeding to check for drawings.")
                    if let drawing = page.drawing {
                     
                     // Create an annotation of our custom subclass
                     let newAnnotation = MyPDFAnnotation(bounds: drawing.bounds,
                                                         forType: .stamp, withProperties: nil)
                     
                     // Add our custom data
                     let codedData = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: drawing,
                                                                       requiringSecureCoding: true)
                     newAnnotation.setValue(codedData,
                                            forAnnotationKey: PDFAnnotationKey(rawValue: "drawingData"))
                     
                     // Add our annotation to the page
                     page.addAnnotation(newAnnotation)
                     
                 } else {
                     print("Page had no drawings")
                     
                 }
                }
                  
            }
            
        }
        
    
        if let resultData = pdfDocument.dataRepresentation() {
            return resultData
        }
        

    }
    
    // Fall through to returning empty data
    return Data()
}

I am not a Swift expert, so initially thought maybe I was working on different instances of the PDFDocument so tried to rework how I store and manage the data to make sure I work on the same instance. This lead to the rather complex model based on a DocumentStore with the documents acting as an EnvironmentObject. However, that did not seem to make a difference.
Any idea what the problem might be?
